# Matlab substring

Tags: string, matlab

I am trying to get average a specific value in a long string and cannot figure out how to pull a value out of the middle of the string. I would like to pull out the 27 from this and the other strings and add them

2015-10-1,33,**27**,20,29,24,20,96,85,70,30.51,30.40,30.13,10,9,4,10,6,,T,5,Snow,35
2015-10-1,33,27,20,29,24,20,96,85,70,30.51,30.40,30.13,10,9,4,10,6,,T,5,Snow,35
2015-10-2,37,32,27,32,27,23,92,80,67,30.35,30.31,30.28,10,10,7,7,4,,T,8,Rain-Snow,19
2015-10-3,39,36,32,35,33,29,100,90,79,30.30,30.17,30.11,10,7,0,8,3,,0.21,8,Fog-Rain,13
2015-10-4,40,37,34,38,36,33,100,96,92,30.23,30.19,30.14,2,1,0,6,0,,0.13,8,Fog-Rain,27
2015-10-5,46,38,30,38,34,30,100,91,61,30.19,30.08,29.93,10,7,0,6,2,,T,6,Fog-Rain,23

```
fid = fopen('MonthlyHistory.html');

for i=1:2
  str = fgets(fid);
  c = strsplit(str,',');
  mean=mean+c;
  end
fprintf('Average Daily Temperature: %d\n',mean);
```

Comment: Is your data HIGHLY structured? can we live or die depending on whether the value you're looking for follows the 2nd comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1: use readtable

I'm guessing this is pulled from weather underground? Take [your csv file](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/FAJS/2001/4/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1) and make sure it is saved with a `.csv` ending. Then what I would do is:

```
my_data = readtable('MonthlyHistory.csv');
```

This reads the whole file into the highly convenient `table` variable type. Then you can do:

```
average_daily_temp = my_data.MeanTemperatureF; %or whatever it is called in the table
```

I find tables are a super convenient way to keep track of tabular data. (plus readtable is pretty good).

#### Method 2: continue your approach...

```
fid = fopen('mh2.csv');

str = fgets(fid); % May need to read off a few lines to get to the
str = fgets(fid); % numbers

my_data = [];     %initialize an empty array

while(true)
    str = fgets(fid);  % read off a line
    if(str == -1)      % if str is -1, which signifies end of file
        break;            %exit loop
    end    
    ca   = strsplit(str,',');  % split string into a cell array of strings
    my_data(end+1,:) = str2num(ca{3}); % convert the 3rd element to a number and store it

end

fclose(fid);
```

Now `my_data` is an array holding the 3rd element of each line.

Comment: Its for a course i am taking on programming, That would work but I have to use an attached .html file. I used srtsplit(str,',') to break it up into substrings but now i have no idea how to add the substrings up.

Comment: what do you mean, 'add the substrings up?'

Comment: And its a .csv file though, correct? That is, it's a bunch of entries separated by commas, not a crazy quantity of html to parse

Comment: its a .html with 31 super long strings

Comment: like add the value [1,3] from spliting the string up its in a loop                                              [1,1] = 2015-10-1
  [1,2] = 33
  [1,3] = 27
  [1,4] = 20
  [1,5] = 29
  [1,6] = 24
  [1,7] = 20
  [1,8] = 96
  [1,9] = 85
  [1,10] = 70
  [1,11] = 30.51
  [1,12] = 30.40
  [1,13] = 30.13
  [1,14] = 10
  [1,15] = 9
  [1,16] = 4
  [1,17] = 10
  [1,18] = 6
  [1,19] = T
  [1,20] = 5
  [1,21] = Snow
  [1,22] = 35<br>

Comment: You can create some empty array `my_temp = []` and then each iteration, do something like `my_temp(end+1) = str2num(value[1,3]);`

Comment: rock on this is exactly what i needed!

Comment: If you're learning Matlab, something to remember: If x is an array, then x(1,3) returns the element at the 1st row, 3rd column. If x is a *cell array*, then x{1,3} returns the element at the 1st row, 3rd column. for *cell arrays*, x(1,3) would return *another cell array*! Thta's why I index ca as ca{3} but I index my_data as my_data(end+1);

Answer (score 2):

You can use `textscan`, you might be able to simplfy your code using this as well, but for a single string, it works like this:

```
S='2015-10-1,33,27,20,29,24,20,96,85,70,30.51,30.40,30.13,10,9,4,10,6,,T,5,Snow,35'
T=textscan(S,'%s','Delimiter',',')
str2double(T{1}{3}) %// the value we want is the 3rd field
```